# How to insert variables in quotes inside quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I am writing a javascript in pug.

I am using express and mongodb to create a crud, and I want to generate an edit button for each post and generate an event.

The result I want is "edit_form_1" but "edit_form_4 {post._id}" is returned.

What mistakes have I made?

I wrote the following code:

**index.pug**

```
...
head
      script.
      function click(id) => {
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        if element.display == 'none' {
          element.display = 'block'
        }
        else {
          element.display = 'none'
        }
      }
...
body
      a(onclick=`click(`div_${post._id}`)`) 수정
      div(id=`div_${post._id}` style="display: none;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may have too many backticks in your first line, try this:

```
a(onclick=`click(div_${post._id})`) 수정
div(id=`div_${post._id}` style="display: none;")
```

Comment: a(onclick = `click(div_${post._id})`) will result in "can not read property 'style' of null '.

Comment: I just edit my answer, try now. After display none there is ending quatation mark missing.